# Wired router in front of a wireless router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, wired-networking

I have an AC3200, R8000 Wifi router.  I want to have a wired-only router with at least 4 (preferably more) ethernet outlets in front of this at the modem and then feed the wireless router from the wired router.  Can i do this simply?  What should I buy as the wired-only router?  (I want to move the wifi origination to a different location but don't want to move some ethernet-wired equipment where the wifi now sits or create longer wired hook-ups.)

Comment: Why do you need a wired router rather than just a switch?

Comment: I don't know anything about networking, so I don't really know what a switch is.  It will all be the same LAN.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the people commenting, or your first answer actually understood your question.

You can't use a switch coming from the modem. In short, it wouldn't work unless you had multiple outside IP addresses. (This is assuming it's not a combo device, but essentially a Coax to Ethernet converter style modem.)

Most residential and SoHo connections do not have Multiple global IP addresses.

Shopping recommendations are off-topic here, choosing a router will be at your discretion. You would want to purchase the router based off of:

1. Your total up down in Mbps from your ISP.
2. The speeds you need to connect to other clients in your LAN. It depends on your devices network interfaces, but 1Gbps seems reasonable with your 802.11AC router.

   A example router would be [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003CFATSS).
   (Note this example router only has 10/100Mbps ports.) You wouldn't want this model if your connecting your WIFI clients to your wireless AC router higher than 100Mbps.

[image: wired to wireless]

Make sure that the link from the two routers is connected LAN to LAN.

Disable any firewall/NAT features in the wireless router. And additionally disable DHCP on this router.

If you have an option for "AP mode" or similar in the WiFi routers configuration page choose it.

Hopefully you didn't already purchase a switch!